# What is the <ColumnDefinition /> used for in Xamarin Forms and can it be replaced with a value setting?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code and I would like to convert the `ColumnDefinition` to use the new syntax where it's on the first line.

Can someone explain to me in this case what is `<ColumnDefinition />` used for:

```
<Grid Margin="5,5,5,0" >

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TitleTapped" />
    </Grid.GestureRecognizers>

    <t:FaqTemplate
        HorizontalOptions="Start"
        Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference _accordion_view_123}, Path=Title}"
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

    <ContentView
        x:Name="_indicatorContainer"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Content="{Binding Source={x:Reference _accordion_view_123}, Path=IndicatorView}"
        HorizontalOptions="End"
        VerticalOptions="Start" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When using the new ColumnDefinition syntax, how can I represent <ColumnDefinition />](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64802635/when-using-the-new-columndefinition-syntax-how-can-i-represent-columndefinitio)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the new syntax, that would translate to:

```
<Grid ColumnDefinitions="*, 50">
```

For the complete specs on the new syntax, you can read this: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/673

Basically, `<ColumnDefinition />` is the equivalent of `<ColumnDefinition Width="*" />` (`*` is the default value for the `Width` property).

The width of a column can be expressed in 3 ways:

- `Auto` means that the column will automatically size itself based on content, within the available space
- absolute values like `50`, in that case the column will be 50 density-independent pixels wide
- or `*` which is actually the equivalent of `1*`. `*` allows you to split the available space proportionally. For example, if you have column A with `1*` and column B with `3*`, column A will occupy 25% (1 of 4) and column B will occupy 75% (3 of 4).

In your particular case, the second column has a fixed value of `50`, so your first column with `*` width will take up 100% of the remaining width after the `50` is subtracted.

You can check out different examples here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/grid-tutorial
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/tutorials/grid/?tabs=vswin

Answer (score 0):

You define two columns, one with a width value of `50` and one with default properties. The one with default properties is `<ColumnDefinition />`.

View the **Xamarin 101** series to learn this:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLdo4fOcmZ0oU10SXt2W58pu2L0v2dOW-1

It is the official series by Microsoft and a most basic entry point for learning Xamarin.

Comment: What is the default property?

Comment: The default value for the `Width` property is `*`.